# Getting YUV from CMSampleBufferRef for video streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, video-streaming, avfoundation

I am building an iOS video streaming chat application and the library I am working with requires that I send the video data passing it the YUV (or I guess YCbCr) data individually.

I have the delegate set up, but I'm not sure how to extra the individual YUV elements from the `CMSampleBufferRef`. Alot of the apple guides from what I seen, reference stuff about capturing video frames to UIImages though.

Stream format

```
- (BOOL)setupWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:error];

    if (! videoInput) {
        return NO;
    }

    [self.captureSession addInput:videoInput];

    self.processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("abcdefghijk", NULL);

    [self.dataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
    NSNumber *value  = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange];

    [self.dataOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value
                                                                  forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
    [self.dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:self.processingQueue];

    return YES;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);


    if (! imageBuffer) {
        return;
    }



    uint16_t width = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    uint16_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    uint8_t yPlane[??] = ???
    uint8_t uPlane[?] = ???
    uint8_t vPlane[?] = ???

    [self.library sendVideoFrametoFriend:self.friendNumber width:width height:height
                                yPlane:yPlane
                                uPlane:uPlane
                                vPlane:vPlane
                                 error:nil];
}
```

Does anyone have any examples or links where I can figure this out?

***Update***
According to https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV there shall be more elements of Y then there are U/V. The library also confirms this as well, nothing the below:

```
 * Y - plane should be of size: height * width
 * U - plane should be of size: (height/2) * (width/2)
 * V - plane should be of size: (height/2) * (width/2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** I've now read how to YUV buffer is composed and this is how you read it. I also made sure that I dont malloc on every frame.

Have fun! ;)

```
//int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);

int yHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer,0);
int uvHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer,1);

int yWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer,0);
int uvWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer,1);

int ybpr = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
int uvbpr = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);

int ysize = yHeight * ybpr ;
int uvsize = uvHeight * uvbpr ;

static unsigned char *ypane;
if(!ypane)
   ypane = (unsigned char*)malloc(ysize);
static unsigned char *upane;
if(!upane)
   upane = (unsigned char*)malloc(uvsize);
static unsigned char *vpane;
if(!vpane)
   vpane = (unsigned char*)malloc(uvsize);

unsigned char *yBase = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(ypane, 0);
unsigned char *uBase = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(upane, 1;
unsigned char *vBase = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(vpane, 2);

for(int y=0,y<yHeight;y++)
{
   for(int x=0,x<yWidth;x++)
   {
      ypane[y*yWidth+x]=yBase[y*ybpr+x];
   }
 }

for(int y=0,y<uvHeight;y++)
{
   for(int x=0,x<uvWidth;x++)
   {
      upane[y*uvWidth+x]=uBase[y*uvbpr+x];
      vpane[y*uvWidth+x]=vBase[y*uvbpr+x];
   }
 }
```

Comment: So in this case the data is set up like so?
`[y][u][v][y][u][v]`. This makes sense, though I'm not sure if I would malloc during realtime video. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the number of elements  should be more for Y. The API also affirms this as well. I'll update my original question

Comment: you don't have to malloc during the live video, you could just make the variables static

Comment: Can you paste the code how you setup the color space for your stream?

Comment: Sure thing, just added!

Comment: I updated it how fitting your code - lemme know whether it works, didnt get the chance to test it

Comment: I got it working, mine implementation is slightly different. Also since it's biplanar, you can only get the 1st and 2nd base. yPlane is [yyyy] uvPlane[uvuvuv]